# http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic in the close reasons popout shouldn't go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Tags: bug, close-reasons, meta, migration, broken-link

Go to a question, click flag and get to this page:

(flag → should be closed… → off topic because… → This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network)

[image: Screenshot of migration list]

You see the top multiple choice answer? <strike>(I would make a circle but I'm too lazy.)</strike> If you click on that link, it redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

That shouldn't be happening. When you reach that page, you are saying this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, it belongs somewhere else. The links give you information on what questions are accepted in these other sites (e.g. click on dba.stackexchange.com). Now when someone tries to see what questions are accepted in Meta, they see Stack Overflow’s criteria!

I don't know if that is just a wrong link, or if there is no on-topic link for meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

We don't have a MSO help, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/help, so naturally this would redirect too.

The proper link, in my opinion, should be [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) (note: still SO help). That has a description of what's on-topic here.